# jQuery add or remove class based on menu item clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried this, searched on StackOverflow.

```
$(".sub>li>a").click(function(e) {
    if( $(this).hasClass("open") ) {
        $(this).removeClass("open").addClass("closed");
    } else {
        // if other menus are open remove open class and add closed
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("open").addClass("closed"); 
        $(this).removeClass("closed").addClass("open");
    }
});
```

But it does not work.

Here is my fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/v2oLfcnf/

Comment: Why are your fiddle and your code on this post different?

Comment: Um, you never stated what your problem was.

Comment: because that's i found codes, i think that's related to my question.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it does not work?"

Comment: jQuery is not added. Use this - https://jsfiddle.net/v2oLfcnf/6/

Answer (score 1):

Maker sure jQuery is included.

```js
var study1= 0;
$("#info").click(function(){
 study1++;
  if(study1%2==1){
   $(".one").fadeIn('fast');
   
   
  }else{
   $(".one").fadeOut();
   $(".two").fadeOut();
   $(".three").fadeOut();
   $(".four").fadeOut();
  }
 }); 
  
  var study= 0;
$("#study").click(function(){
 study++;
  if(study%2==1){
   $(".two").fadeIn('fast');
   
  }else{
   $(".one").fadeOut();
   $(".two").fadeOut();
   $(".three").fadeOut();
   $(".four").fadeOut();
  }
 });
  
  $(".sub>li>a").click(function(e) {

    if( $(this).hasClass("open") ) {
        $(this).removeClass("open").addClass("closed");
    } else {
        // if other menus are open remove open class and add closed
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("open").addClass("closed"); 
        $(this).removeClass("closed").addClass("open");
    }
});
```

```css
 a{
   text-decoration: none;
   color: white;
  }
  a:hover{
   color: #D8B490;
  }
  
  li{
   text-decoration: none;
   list-style: none;
  
  }
    .sub{
 position: relative;

 top: 20%;
}
#info,#study,#edu,#sup{
   display: inline-block;z-index: 5;
   position: relative;
  
   margin: 2%;
   
  }
  #top{
  z-index: 80;
  background:#D8B490;
  width: 100%;}
.menu{
  position: absolute;
  top:5%;
   background: /*#69341C;*/ #302F42;
   color: white;
   height: 100px;
   z-index:55;
  width: 100%;
   }
.sub{
 display: inline-block;
 
}


/*hide menu, if clicked .sub>li>a , fadeIn() below*/
  .one{
 
   width: 50%;
   height: 20%;
   display: block;
   background: white;
   position: absolute;
   left: 40%;
   top: 88%;
   color: red;
   display: none;
  }

  .two{
  display: none;
    color: red;
   width: 50%;
   height: 20%;
   
   background: white;
   position: absolute;
   left: 40%;
   top: 88%;
   
  }
  
  .three{
   display: none;
    color: red;
   width: 50%;
   height: 20%;
   
   background: white;
   position: absolute;
   left: 40%;
   top: 88%;
  }
  .four{
   display: none;
   
   width: 50%;
   height: 20%;
    color: red;
   background: white;
   position: absolute;
   left: 40%;
   top: 88%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
   <ul class="sub">
    <li>
     <a href="#" id="info"> infomation</a>
    </li>
     
   </ul>
   
   
   <ul class="one">
      <li>a</li>
      <li>b</li>
     </ul>
   
   
   
   <ul class="sub">
    <li>
     <a href="#" id="study"> study</a>
    
    </li>
     
   </ul>
   <ul class="two">
      <li>c</li>
      <li>d</li>
     </ul>
     
     
   <ul class="sub">
    <li>
     <a href="#" id="edu">edu</a>
    
    </li>
     
   </ul>
   <ul class="three">
      <li>e</li>
      <li>f</li>
     </ul>
   
   
   
   
   <ul class="sub">
    <li>
     <a href="#" id="sup">support</a>
    
    </li>
     
   </ul>
   
   <ul class="four">
      <li>g</li>
      <li>h</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to have a generic status (closed), and on click, toggle class open which would be more specific ? I'm just assuming that the initial state is closed

```
<style>
    .closed {
        /*code*/
    }
    div.open {
        /*status when open*/
    }
</style>
<script>
    $(.closed).on('click', function(){
        this.toggleClass('open');
    }
</script>
```

I'm not an expert with jQuery syntax but this might work

edit :

jQuery might be pretty heavy just for this, don't hesitate to look at [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) which is implemented on every browser nowaday

Answer (score 0):

the `$` syntax is not a built-in Javascript API. You must have jQuery in your project in order to use it.

Just add this line, which include jquery in your project:

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
```

I updated your fiddle with the code https://jsfiddle.net/v2oLfcnf/

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle didn't work because it didn't include a link to jQuery anywhere. I have since [updated your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v2oLfcnf/7/) and it seems to work now. 
See "External Resources" to the left in the fiddle window. Add a link to jQuery there, i.E.: `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/v2oLfcnf/8/

```js
$('.sub > li > a').click(function(){
  $('.sublist').fadeOut();
  $(this).closest('ul.sub').next('ul.sublist').fadeIn();
});
```

```css
a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
a:hover{
  color: #D8B490;
}

li{
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;

}
.sub{
 position: relative;
 top: 20%;
}

#info,#study,#edu,#sup{
  display: inline-block;z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2%;
}

#top{
  z-index: 80;
  background:#D8B490;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu{
  position: absolute;
  top:5%;
  background: /*#69341C;*/ #302F42;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
  z-index:55;
  width: 100%;
}
.sub{
  display: inline-block;
}


/*hide menu, if clicked .sub>li>a , fadeIn() below*/
.one{
  width: 50%;
  height: 20%;
  display: block;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  top: 88%;
  color: red;
  display: none;
}

.two{
  display: none;
  color: red;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20%;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  top: 88%;   
}
  
.three{
  display: none;
  color: red;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20%;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  top: 88%;
}

.four{
  display: none;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20%;
  color: red;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  top: 88%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="sub">
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="info"> infomation</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
 <ul class="one sublist">
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
  </ul>
 <ul class="sub">
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="study"> study</a>
    </li>
 </ul>
  <ul class="two sublist">
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
  </ul>
     
 <ul class="sub">
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="edu">edu</a>
    </li>   
  </ul>
  <ul class="three sublist">
    <li>e</li>
    <li>f</li>
  </ul>
 <ul class="sub">
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="sup">support</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
   
  <ul class="four sublist">
    <li>g</li>
    <li>h</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.